# get products by user id in magento

Tags: magento

How to get user id of magento admin panel, suppose i have created a account in magento admin panel named as user1 and user2 and giving the permission to add a product, then i want to know that user1 entered product and as well as user2 entered product?

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. What do you mean by "Admin ID"? What does that have to do with user1 and user2? What is "entering product collection"? What about adding punctuation and using proper grammar? ...

Comment: Can you give more information about your question?

Comment: Hi balanv i am adding a product form fronted using get and set method i want to get collection of products based on user how have created that product.

Comment: very complicated question. as far as I understand, you would like to create a product from magento frontside instead of admin panel. right? or what do you want do!

Comment: yes i have created product from fronted and i want get product collection, suppose user1 is created a products and i want to get collection of product created by user1.

Comment: In this scenario user can create his own product and sale it and store owner get commission on the basis of sale isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long try i got the solution.
It worked for me.

```
 
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $read= $resource->getConnection('core_read');
            $event_attending = $resource->getTableName('event_attending');

            $select = $read->select('event_id')
                   ->from($event_attending)
                   ->where('user_id = ?',$session->getId())
                   ->order('event_date DESC') ;                
            $attending_events = $read->fetchAll($select);
            $resultArray = '';$str='';
            foreach($attending_events as $attEvent){
                if($str!='')$str.=',';              

                    $str.=$attEvent['event_id'];
            }
            //echo $str;
             $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
             if($session->isLoggedIn()){
                $events = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => array($str)))
                            ->load(); 
                //print_r($events->toArray());
                return $events;
            }
            else
                return '';
   }
```

Comment: event_attending is magento default table or you customize it if you customized then please let me know that what table is event_attending in magento

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getData();

$userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId();
$userEmail = $user->getUser()->getEmail();
$userFirstname = $user->getUser()->getFirstname();
$userLastname = $user->getUser()->getLastname();
$userUsername = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
$userPassword = $user->getUser()->getPassword();



$adminuser = Mage::getSingleton()->getUser();
 $roleId = implode('', $adminuser->getRoles());
 $userId = $adminuser->getId();
```